# Tableau - Add a filter into your dashboard

Tags: tableau-desktop

How do I add an additional filter object onto my Tableau dashboard?

For example in the below, I want to add a filter object that is a dropdown menu that I can use to select different Genres:

Ideal:
[image]

Current:
[image]
I tried creating adding a blank "Vertical" Object but there is no way for me to fill it in with the Genres sheet (tried Shift clicking and dragging from "Sheets" but does not work).

Comment: please read about layouts in tableau, just a bit practice will let you figure it out